# using python-requests to access a site with captcha

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, captcha

I've searched the web on how to access a website using request, essentially the site ask the user to complete a captcha form before they can access the site.

As of now I understand the process should be

- visit the site using selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
browser.get('link-to-site')
```

- complete the captcha form
- save the cookies from that selenium session (since some how these cookies will contain data showing that you've completed captcha

```
input('cookies ready ?')
pickle.dump( browser.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

- open a request session
- get the site

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
r = session.get('link-to-site')
```

- then load the cookies in

```
with open('cookies.pkl', 'r') as f:
    cookies = requests.utils.cookiejar_from_dict(json.load(f))
    session.cookies.update(cookies)
```

But I'm still unable to access the site, so I'm assuming the google captcha hasn't been solved when I'm using requests.

So there must be a correct way to go about this, I must be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the site after setting the cookies. Otherwise, the response is what the response would be without any cookies. Although having said that you will normally need to submit the form with selenium then list the cookies as a captcha doesn't normally set a cookie in itself.